# How can I get the Primary Key for the DbSet?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I use Net Core 1.1 and Entity Framework Core with the fluent API.  I am writing a simple extension method for DbSet to show its entities in Console:

```
public static class DbSetExtension
{
    public static void Show<T>(this DbSet<T> set) where T:class
    {

        WriteLine();
        WriteLine($"Set: {typeof(T).Name} - {set.Count()} objects.");
        WriteLine();

        foreach (var e in set)
        {
            WriteLine(e);
        }

        WriteLine();
        WriteLine();
    }
}
```

This works but I'd like to have the entities sorted by the primary key before showing them. If I had the `DbContext` it would have been easily accomplished by doing something like this:

```
var entityType = db.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T));
var primaryKeyName = entityType.FindPrimaryKey().Properties.First().Name;
var set = db.Set<T>();
var orderedEntities = (set.OrderBy(e=> e.GetType().GetProperty(primaryKeyName).GetValue(e,null))).ToList();
```

Is there a way to get the same result starting from the `DbSet`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible, but not "officially" - you have to use some methods marked as *This API supports the Entity Framework Core infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.*.

You basically utilize the fact that `DbSet<T>` implements `IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>`, so you can obtain [`IDbContextServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.internal.idbcontextservices) via `GetService` method in order to get the model from [`Model`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.internal.idbcontextservices#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Internal_IDbContextServices_Model) property:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal;

...
var model = set.GetService<IDbContextServices>().Model;
var entityType = model.FindEntityType(typeof(T));
var properties = entityType.GetProperties();
var primaryKeyName = entityType.FindPrimaryKey().Properties.First().Name;
var sortedSet = (set.OrderBy(e=> e.GetType().GetProperty(primaryKeyName).GetValue(e,null))).ToList();
...
```

Comment: GetService is not a method on DbSet anymore.

Comment: @RogerFar That's not true. It is still there - in latest official 3.1 as well as 5.0 preview. Probably you've missed the "non official" (internal) API part and the required `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;` - the aforementioned method is an extension method inside `AccessorExtensions` class inside that namespace. So I have to "disappoint" you, but the above code is still working :)